# How to add string value in CPtrList?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

How to add a string into cptrlist? I am using visual studio 6.0.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways to do this. All depends on what you want to do exactly.

For example :

```
CPtrList MyList ;

...

  CPtrList MyList ;
  MyList.AddTail("Test") ;

  CString str ;
  str = .... ;
  MyList.AddTail(&str) ;
```